# Read registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Error Reporting\Local Dumps\ values?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Goal: to determine the values of the following registry entries, if they exist

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Error Reporting\Local Dumps\DumpCount
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Error Reporting\Local Dumps\DumpType
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Error Reporting\Local Dumps\DumpFolder

These were set up according to [Microsoft instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using regedit.

The program requiring this information is native C++, 32-bit, built using VS2013, running on one of these platforms: 32-bit XP, 32- or 64-bit Vista, 32- or 64-bit Windows 7, 32- or 64-bit Windows 8 or 8.1. In the future, the program will have a 64-bit version as well.

My first attempt was

```
UINT dumpCount = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Error Reporting\\Local Dumps",
"DumpCount", -1/*nDefault*/);
```

This returns -1 (value not found).

Next, I tried

```
openErr = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Error Reporting\\Local Dumps", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);
regErr = RegQueryValueEx(key, "DumpCount", 0, &type, (BYTE*)data, &sizeD);
```

`RegOpenKeyEx` gives `openErr`=2 (path not found), but

```
openErr = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);
```

succeeds (`openErr`=0).

Perhaps this is a [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) issue? If so, how do I get the key values I am looking for, in such a way that it will work on any of the specified platforms? I do not need to write anything to the registry.

Comment: If the program is working on 32-bit systems but not 64-bit systems, the problem is the registry redirector.  If it doesn't work on 32-bit systems either, it's something else.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: I haven't tried it on a 32-bit system, and it would take a lot more work to do so. In any case, it needs to work on a 64-bit system.

Comment: OK, so if you used the 64-bit version of regedit and didn't explicitly put the data into Wow6432Node, the data is in the 64-bit part of the registry.  Use the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag to open it from a 32-bit application.